# Why are there some unnecessary lines in matplotlib colorbars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am not sure if this is a local problem or happens to every one. But when I use colorbars in matplotlib and save them in PDF format I get certain unwanted lines in the colorbar as shown below:

[image]

A closer view:

[image]

[image]

The code I used is:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
fig.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
plt.specgram(data, NFFT = 256, Fs = sampling_rate)
plot.grid(False, which="major")
plot.set_xlabel(r'\textit{Time (s)}', labelpad=6)
plot.set_ylabel(r'\textit{{Frequency (Hz)}}', labelpad=6)
plt.colorbar()
fig.savefig('specgram.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Is there some way of removing this unnecessary lines?

Comment: did you try just plotting it instead of saving it to see if the lines still exist?

Comment: and why do you need `plot.grid(False, which="major")`??

Comment: Because I have set grids on in matplotlibrc parameter file.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with some vector graphics *viewers* (i.e. not with matplotlib *per se*). Some viewers will render gaps between the segments of the gradient. The `plt.colorbar` [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=colorbar#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar) contains a simple workaround: set the edge colour for each segment to its face colour, as follows.

```
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
```